# iterate 2 dicts and compare values then append inner list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, compare

I am faced with a situation where I need to iterate nested dicts with same outermost keys, compare inner key value to inner key value of other dict then append. Below will help to understand:

```
{AD:{(62,'VMX','Barcelona','ES'): ['123','567','666'}} #dict1  many more rows

{AD:{(151,'CMXS','','ES','62'): ['345','6754']}}       #dict 2 many more rows
```

So I need to iterate both dicts, compare tuple key[0] of dict1 == tuple key[4] of dict2, if they match append inner list in dict1 with inner list in dict2.

after this dict1 looks like

```
{AD:{(62,'VMX','Barcelona','ES'): ['123','567','666','345','6754'}}
```

Wrote this code but it not working as expected

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    if len(v)!= 0:
        for c,a in dict2.items():
            if len(a)!= 0:
                for k2,v2 in v.items():
                    for c2,a2 in a.items():
                        if str(k2[0]) == c2[4]:
                            v2.append(a2)
```

Comment: There are only two levels of depth right ?

Comment: Yes only 2 levels deep, but issue with this nested loop is that, it also appends for all other cases where str(k2[0]) == c2[4]). as in where outermost key is different from AD.

Comment: If you want the outermost key to be the same, add an `and k == c` condition. i.e. `if (k == c) and (str(k2[0]) == c2[4])`

Comment: alternatively, skip the second for loop and only loop over dictionaries that have the same outer key. `a = dict2[k]`.

Comment: @algrebe Hi your first comment makes it work. Could you explain what you mean by get rid of second for loop please? hating the 2 nested loops. Lot of unncessary comparisons

Comment: @NaiveBayes so since your condition to append to v2 requires `k == c`, there is no need to iterate over all `c,a in dict2.items()`. Instead, just get `a` from `dict2[k]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict1 = {"AD":{(62,'VMX','Barcelona','ES'): ['123','567','666']}} #dict1  many more rows

dict2 = {"AD":{(151,'CMXS','','ES','62'): ['345','6754']}}       #dict 2 many more rows

# create a simplified map of dict2
dict3 = {}
for outer_key, outer_value_dict in dict2.items():
    for inner_key_tuple, inner_value_list in outer_value_dict.items():
        new_key = (outer_key, inner_key_tuple[4]) # e.g. (AD, 62)
        dict3.setdefault(new_key, []).extend(inner_value_list)

# now modify dict1 using dict3 instead of dict2
for outer_key, outer_value in dict1.items():
    for inner_key_tuple, inner_value_list in outer_value.items():
        lookup_key = (outer_key, str(inner_key_tuple[0]))
        # search dict3 using the lookup_key.
        # if not present, get will return an empty list
        list_to_extend = dict3.get(lookup_key, [])
        inner_value_list.extend(list_to_extend)

print(dict1)
```

Output

```
/tmp $ python test.py.py
{'AD': {(62, 'VMX', 'Barcelona', 'ES'): ['123', '567', '666', '345', '6754']}}
```

Based on the comments, since you wanted to know how to avoid one of the loops - here's an updated version

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    a = dict2.get(k)
    if a is None or len(v) == 0:
        continue

    for k2,v2 in v.items():
        for c2,a2 in a.items():
            if str(k2[0]) == c2[4]:
                v2.append(a2)
```

Comment: This makes it cleaner. I thought there was a way to avoid making another dict. But this does the job. Thank you.

Comment: I've also updated it with what I meant in the comments

Comment: please comment on this. It doesnt work due to next not being iterated  ```for k,v in dict1.items():
    if len(v)!= 0:
        for k2,v2 in v.items():
            if str(k2[0]) == next(iter(dict2[k]))[4]:
                
                v2.append(dict2[k][next(iter(dict2[k]))])```

Comment: @NaiveBayes could you elaborate more on your comment? Are you trying something new? An alternate approach?

Comment: No I am doing the same thing that I did with 2 loops, using above method. Not sure how to add space in comments. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: @NaiveBayes `next(iter(dict2[k]))`. Firstly, this assumes k is part of dict2. If it isn't, you will get a KeyError. Which is why I use `.get(k)` and check if it is None. Also, this will always compare k2[0] against a single key in dict2[k]. You want it to compare against every tuple who's 4th element matches k2[0]. So you can't get rid of the `for c2,a2 in a.items()` for loop.

Comment: Ahh. I thought I could somehow get rid of that loop and used next. But it only returns 1 key. Both your solutions above are insighful. Thanks a ton for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The for loops are placed correctly as long as the example goes.

What do you mean by unexpectedly?
Do you mean this?

```
{'AD': {(62, 'VMX', 'Barcelona', 'ES'): ['123', '567', '666', ['345', '6754']]}}
```

That extra array within the array?

Because if so, the answer would be to switch the .append() with a .extend()

Comment: Hi, is there a better way than using 2 nested loops, considering this is not efficient for big dicts or if i need to compare 3 dicts? The append/extend is not the problem. The issue is with the values being appended. The comment from @algrebe fixes the issue. But would still like to know a better way